# Codeigniter captcha file name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing an application in codeigniter in my localhost environment.

I am using captcha helper. It creates a temp captcha image inside the captcha folder, for example an image name: **1458602120.1544.jpg**.

Today i moved to digitalocean and installed lampp and now it creates the captcha image with comma not dot, for example image name: **1458602120,1544.jpg**.

Inserting in captcha database table does not work because of the comma character.

```
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
INSERT INTO `captcha` (`captcha_time`, `ip_address`, `word`) VALUES (1458658443,4301, 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX', 'kWlPqs')
```

Any idea on how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fixed my problem by changing the system helper file at lines:

`captcha_helper.php:307` and `captcha_helper.php:315`

with :

```
$img_name = str_replace(',', '.', $now).'.jpg';

ImageJPEG($im, $img_path.$img_name);

$img = "<img src=\"$img_url$img_name\" width=\"$img_width\" height=\"$img_height\" style=\"border:0;\" alt=\" \" />";

ImageDestroy($im);

return array('word' => $word, 'time' => str_replace(',', '.', $now), 'image' => $img);
```

**I added str_replace for variable $now**.